# Angular2 router gets me other url route

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm handling these routes on my Angular2 web application: `''`, `'/app'`, `'/login'`, `'/signin'`, `'/validate'`, `'/error'`, `'**'`:

I've created a route configuration on `app.router.ts`:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [{
   path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'
  }, {
    path: 'app',   loadChildren: () => System.import('./layout/layout.module')
  }, {
    path: 'login', loadChildren: () => System.import('./login/login.module')
  }, {
    path: 'signin', loadChildren: () => System.import('./signin/signin.module')
  }, {
    path: 'validate', loadChildren: () => System.import('./validate/validate.module')
  }, {
    path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent
  }, {
    path: '**',    component: ErrorComponent
  }
];
```

Only `'/validate'` route have to recollect query parameters. Take a look on `Validate` module and component:

```
export const routes = [
  {path: '', component: Validate}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // Components / Directives/ Pipes
    Validate
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ]
})
export default class ValidateModule {
  static routes = routes;
}

----------------

import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { UsersService, UserDTO } from 'cest/ts';

@Component({
  selector: '[validate]',
  templateUrl: './validate.template.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['./validate.style.scss'],
  providers: [ UsersService ]
})
export class Validate implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private id: string;
  private token: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private userService: UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit():void {
    this.sub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'] || undefined;
      this.token = params['token'] || undefined;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

I'm facing up with a trouble related with how `router` tries to get the correct module/component.

The problem is I'm trying to get this url: `http://localhost:3002/validate?id=am9yZGkxMEBsaXZpbmctZGlnaXRhbC13YXkuY29t&token=Ra8i4mrGbz1tf9y9vJHLAd-TKHNH0Ig8o699jXU1YU4%3D-`.

As you can see this url is composed by two query parameters: `id` and `token`. I don't know why Angular2 router after having set this url on browser url location it's redirected to this url: `http://localhost:3002/validate?id=am9yZGkxMEBsaXZpbmctZGlnaXRhbC13YXkuY29t&token=Ra8i4mrGbz1tf9y9vJHLAd-TKHNH0Ig8o699jXU1YU4%3D-#/login`.

The last one is the firstone appending `#/login` path.

Any ideas?

Comment: share code of `UsersService`

Answer (score 0):

Set your app modul's path for validation as

```
{
    path: 'validate/:id/:token', loadChildren: () => System.import('./validate/validate.module')
}
```

and then check